# Am i able to do a search for duplicates in the database?

Tags: duplicate-contacts

If I am looking to clean up my database can I do a mass search for duplicates?  save the file and at a later date work on merging?

Answer (score 7):

Yes - go to **Contacts menu » Find and Merge Duplicate Contacts**.  There is [dedupe documentation](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/common-workflows/deduping-and-merging/) available.

The tricky question is, "What represents a duplicate contact?".  For some organizations, two contacts with the same record might be a duplicate; for others, that's not enough to determine if it's a duplicate.

So while the [Using rules and merging duplicate contacts manually](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/common-workflows/deduping-and-merging/#using-rules-and-merging-duplicate-contacts-manually) section of the documentation might be all you need (e.g. if you can use the built-in "match on emails only" rule), you may need to read the rest to tell CiviCRM what constitutes a duplicate for your organization.

Comment: Thank you,  this step is already done,  I am looking to do a mass search of the database and have it pull duplication's. Do you know if that is  that possible?

Comment: When you click "Use Rule" as specified in the link I sent, you should get a list of duplicates.  If that's not what you need, could you please clarify how it doesn't meet your needs?

Answer (score 1):

There is also the [Extended Contact Matcher](https://github.com/systopia/de.systopia.xcm) extension which could be used to match duplicates. This extension is more enhanced than the default dedupe functionality.

Comment: Can this show a list of duplicates for a given contact?  It's a cool extension but the docs suggest it won't meet this particular need.

Comment: You are right, it doesn't probably fit. I do think it can show a list, but how that exactly works I dont know.